# AWS Amplify hosted React App url redirects is tricky

Tags: reactjs, webpack, amazon-ec2, react-router, aws-amplify

my main issue is in the title. Background: I built a React web app, hosted on AWS Amplify, and a Node/Express server, hosted on AWS EC2 with nginx running as a reverse proxy. Additionally I used Webpack and React-Router (important maybe). My front-end handles all routing and views, my back-end doesn't send anything to render to the front-end, only data. When my app is running on localhost and Netlify, there's no issue.

I've done a ton of research and, according to the post: [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually), it would appear that my problem is caused by the client-side routing used in my app and the fact that that when the page reloads or refreshes. The reason being when the page loads for the first time it doesn't have anything to render yet so it sends a request to the server, which in my case doesn't send a response back.

I read that having a catch-all file that would alway direct to the bundle to the index page in the dist file, and also having an index.html page sent from the back-end, could work. I have tried using a catch-all route. Shown in the code blocks below, I have a _redirects page which does get included in the dist folder (at least when I run npm run build myself), but it doesn't have an effect.

**EDIT**
It took a lot of testing but I managed to fix everything by playing around in the AWS console and applying the redirects / rewrites from there rather than from webpack. I done played myself trying round-about solutions rather than go straight to the source, that being AWS. Another issue adding to my confusion was the react doc's and other people's mentioning of making requests to the server, often citing the back-end server, which made me forget that AWS amplify also acts as a server

**Webpack:**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|png|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader' }]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'public/index.html'
        }),
        new CopyPlugin([
            { from: 'public/_redirects' }
        ])
    ],
    mode: process.env_NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
    devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }
};
```

**Redirect file:**

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `to` key to the `CopyPlugin` configuration object like so:

```
new CopyPlugin([
 { from: './public/_redirects' },
 { to: './public/ }
])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, I tried but to no avail. That actually creates a new file in the dist folder and puts the _redirects file into it, I think if you don't have a 'to' it just copy and spits out the file in the root dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as of Dec 2022 and this is how I solved it via the aws console:

[image]

Redirect rules:

```
/<*> /index.html 404rewrite
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/> /index.html 200rewrite
```